# user_load by a user profile field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, user-profile

I'm trying to login users by detecting it's facebook user id.
"profile_fbuid" is a (hidden) profile field that I created to login users with the corresponding facebook user id.
When a user tries to login with Facebook I detect his/her facebook user id, but when I try to match with corresponding Drupal user this line doesn't work:

```
    $user_exists = user_load(array('profile_fbuid'=>$fbuserid));
```

I get this error: **user warning: Unknown column 'profile_fbuid'**

I know what the error means, but I don't know how can I search a user using a user profile field.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no field in the `users` table called `profile_fbuid`, so I assume you generated this field by using the user profile module.

I think it's better to create a query which gets the `uid` of this column and then passes it to the `user_load()` function.

```
$query = db_query("select `uid` from {table_name} where `profile_fbuid` = %d ",$fbuserid );

while($result = db_fetch_object($query)){
  $uid = $result->uid ; 
  $user_exists = user_load(array('uid'=>$uid));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a custom field that is attached to the user profile called `profile_fbuid`. What you want to do in the database is look for this table:

```
field_data_field_profile_fbuid.
```

The relevant columns are `entity_id`, which will be the (Drupal) `user id`, and `field_profile_fbuid_value`, which will contain the value (the Facebook UID).